# What am I doing wrong with this menu in C

Tags: c

I am new at C and am trying to create my first menu! But whenever the user inputs `1` and enter the default option appears and reload the menu. Although when `4` and enter are hit the default option also appears but the menu is successfully exited.

```
void begin_menu(void)
{
    int choice;

    do
    {
        printf("English Draughts - Main Menu\n\n");
        printf("1. Play Game\n");
        printf("2. Display Winners\n");
        printf("3. Reset Scoreboard\n");
        printf("4. Quit\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case '1' : play();
                break;
            case '2' : /*write function to do here */
                break;
            case '3' : /*write function to do here */
                break;
            case '4' :
                printf("Goodbye!\n");
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Please insert a correct choice.\n");
                break; 
        }
    } while (choice != 4);
}

void play(void)
{
    while(end != "n");
    {
        printf("Player Names\n\n");
        printf("Enter name for first player:\n");
        scanf("%s",&player_one);
        printf("Enter name for second player:\n");
        scanf("%s",&player_two);
        printf("Begin?(y to start, n to quit)\n");
        scanf("%c",&end);
    }
    return;
}
```

Thanks everyone, but I have the problem that if play() is called.. ie 1 is entered.. the console just looks for input and doesn't print the function information at all.

Answer (score 6):

`'1'`and `1` are not the same thing

The first one is an ascii character, the second one is a number.

You can lookup the value of `'1'` in the ascii table and see that it is 49, which does not equal 1.

Try entering 49 in your console, just for fun :)

Comment: That is what I originally thought but if I keep the 1 and remove the 's it just keeps looking for input.

Comment: @user3925467 What do you mean "it keeps looking for input" ? Print the value of `choice`before your switch if you be sure of it

Comment: Ah yes the menu options work correctly now but the function for case 1 is the problem. If I hit 1 and enter right now it just looks for input instead of running the loop in play()

Answer (score 2):

You are evaluating strings instead of integers.

You defined the choice variable as an integer, so comparisons must be with integers to. Remove the ' around your numbers inside your switch statement and it should work fine.

Comment: '1' is not a string, it's a character.

Comment: That is what I tried first but the program just keeps looking for input if I enter numbers after changing the cases.

Answer (score 2):

You are having choice as integer data type.

`int choice;`

But in `switch` case you are checking for character constants. So it leads to `default` case always. Because `'1'` and `1` are not same!

Try the below changes-

```
switch (choice)
{
case 1 : play();
break;
case 2 : /*write function to do here */
break;
case 3 : /*write function to do here */
break;
case 4 : printf("Goodbye!\n");
exit(0);
break;
default: printf("Please insert a correct choice.\n");
break; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `case '1'` instead of `case 1`
'1' is an ascii character and 1 is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, `'1'` and `1` are not the same. `'1'` has a decimal value of `49`. You can fix your code by:

- changing `choice` to be type of `char` and then tell scanf to expect format of `%c`, not `%d`
- or you can change your switch cases to use decimal values.

Switch cases accepts only integer constants. All of the cases are evaluated to integers, hence your code works. Note that switch cases won't work with string literals. If you would type `"1"` instead of `'1'` you would get a compiler error.